# How to get sibling tag values in XML using python ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I've been trying to get the value of the `ci-name` element whose sibling `RandomAttribute`'s value(text) is IMPORTANT. I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying using Python's inbuilt ElementTree.

Here's the sample XML:

```
<state>
    <s-name>State 1</s-name>
    <district>
        <d-name>District 1</d-name>
        <city>
            <ci-name>City 1</ci-name>
            <RandomAttribute>UN- IMPORTANT</RandomAttribute>
        </city>
        <city>
            <ci-name>City 2</ci-name>
            <RandomAttribute>NOT SO IMPORTANT</RandomAttribute>
        </city>
        <city>
            <ci-name>City 3</ci-name>
            <RandomAttribute>IMPORTANT</RandomAttribute>
        </city>
    </district>
</state>
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Can you use lxml?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting Yes

Answer (score 4):

You can access the value with the XPath-1.0 expression

```
/state/district/city[RandomAttribute='IMPORTANT']/ci-name
```

Just put this into a Python XML processor.
In `lxml` this can look like

```
xml = ...
tree = etree.parse(xml)
result = tree.xpath('/state/district/city[RandomAttribute='IMPORTANT']/ci-name')
print(result[0].tag)
```

Output should be

> City 3

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution in one line like the previous one, but I like to keep track of how the XML is structured.

Maybe this helps you understand how ElementTree works?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = 'temp.xml'
xmltree = ET.parse(xml)
cities = xmltree.findall('district')[0].findall('city')
for city in cities:
    RandAttribute = city.findall('RandomAttribute')[0].text
    if RandAttribute == "IMPORTANT":
        ci_name = city.findall('ci-name')[0].text
        print(ci_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.etree as etree
```

if xml you are taking about is string then

```
xml_xpath = "/state/district/city[RandomAttribute='IMPORTANT']/ci-name/text()"
XML_dom = etree.XML(xml)
XML_XPATH_name = etree.XPath(xml_xpath)
return XML_XPATH_name(XML_dom)
```